# Expressing correlation coefficient as average absolute differences between two repeated measurements on the same subjects?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, repeated-measures

I sometimes have to perform sample size calculations during the planning of a study. For some of these calculations, a correlation coefficient is needed as input. In my experience, the experts involved find it quite tricky to translate their experience into realistic values for the correlation. That's why I'm interested in other ways to elicit the correlation by re-expressing it as average absolute difference.

Specifically, assume that $n$ subjects are measured twice using the same instrument. Presumably, the two measurements of the same subject are correlated, say with correlation coefficient $\rho$. Information about the means and variances at both time points is available.

As an example: Assume that systolic blood pressure is measured before and after some intervention. The pre-intervention mean and variance are $130$ mmHg and $169$ mmHg$^2$. The post-intervention mean and variance are $118$ mmHg and $169$ mmHg$^2$. We assume a correlation of $0.65$ between pre- and post-measurements.

**Question:** How can (if at all) the correlation coefficient be expressed as average absolute differences between the two measurements from the same subjects?

This is somewhat analogous to [Gini's mean difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_difference) which is the average distance between two measurements of two randomly drawn observations.

**Edit:** The answer is given in the paper by Vila et al. (2024) in section 4.1. The expression (equation 14 in the paper) is complicated but the results match my simulations with arbitrary means, standard deviations and correlations.

**References**

Vila, R., Balakrishnan, N., & Saulo, H. (2024). An upper bound and a characterization for Gini’s mean difference based on correlated random variables. Statistics & Probability Letters, 207, 110032. ([link to arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.07229)).